# Non-linearity of a phase to voltage converter

Tags: analog

I have found a simple phase to voltage converter as shown in the right hand side of the following picture. The timing diagram is also shown in the left. It is easy to show that the maximum output voltage up to which the capacitor maintains linear charging behavior is below one threshold voltage of M2, which is about 0.6V in 180nm CMOS process. [image]

Assuming a 0.3V margin for the output voltage we ensure that the capacitor never gets charged above 0.3V. So excellent linearity is achieved for a given maximum phase difference by proper choice of C1 and current source M1.

But there are some issues with the circuit. The most critical one is perhaps the significant fall and rise times of the input signals start and stop. As start signal makes a 1-0 go the M3 current does not fall linearly because of delayed shutdown of start signal. Similarly as the stop signal transitions high the capacitor current cannot be shut down instantly due to slow switching time of stop signal. Therefore these two non-linear charging regions cause some of the phase information to be lost.

In my opinion the slow switching time of start and stop signals is inevitable and can only be mitigated by adopting more advanced CMOS technology processes. But for the current CMOS technology I am using the problem is evident. What else do you suggest to solve the problem?

Typical phase difference range: 0-1ns

Typical rise/fall time range: 30-50ps

Comment: Use CML logic….

Comment: You also have floating charge in M2,M3 (from gate-source, gate-drain capacitance) which switching the FETs will dump onto C1. From my sample/hold days, faster switching times will only dump this charge faster, not change its magnitude...

Comment: @user_1818839 Yes I agree. Also a fast change in the drain voltage of M1 causes VBIAS fluctuation through gate-drain capacitor. This adds some non-linearity too. I'm trying to solve these problems later after this one is solved.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I have never heard about CML logic. Looks interesting idea. I'm trying to learn and see what improvement I can make with this logic.

Comment: What happens when both start and stop are high?

Comment: @AJN This is the reset phase and the capacitor discharges to 0V.

Comment: HOTLink II CML Is 50ps min, there are faster ways

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Do you think CML logic is worth considering over conventional CMOS logic for switching frequencies in the range 10-50MHz? In my application both start and stop switch in the range of a few tens of MHz.

Comment: That’s not what you asked in your question

Comment: I think it over complicates my design. Especially I would have to move between CMOS and CML logics as I have CMOS logics in parts of the design.

Comment: Are M1 and M2 backwards? Their body diodes would throw off any attempt to use M1 as a current source or M2 as a switch.

Comment: @Hearth Yes right, sorry about the wrong connections. I made the schematic in a hurry